# Expresso Store: Update Cart button is not updating the cart

Tags: expresso-store

I have a regular 'update cart button' on my basket (button type="submit" name="update_cart"), which should obviously recalculate the cart when I click it.

The cart is reloading correctly, but any changes to quantity are being ignored and the original value reloaded.

Any pointers as to where this might be going wrong?

Comment: Is this a local site or on a staging server? I'm having a similar issue on localhost.

Comment: When you say the cart is reloading correctly, what do you mean? Does the page just refresh? Try removing your htaccess file and see if it works using the standard `index.php/template-group` URLs.

Comment: Check to see that you do not have a minimum quantity set to the product (something so simple ... has tripped me up before!)

Comment: It's on a staging server, I'm sure it used to work! The page refreshes, but the quantity hasn't updated. I had problems with the htaccess when I first moved to my VPS, but I thought I had fixed them all. Thanks for the suggestions, will try them out.

Comment: It turns out that there is no error with my site, just that 'limit stock' was turned on, and everything was set to '1' in the inventory !!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there is no error with my site, just that 'limit stock' was turned on, and everything was set to '1' in the inventory!
This means that only 1 item could be added to the cart anyway (but no error message meant that it wasn't clear what then issue was)