# Adding items to cart

Tags: expresso-store

I am new to the Store module. Store module is working only the Control Panel logged in members. If I'm not logged into the Control Panel, Side bar Cart is showing that: "Your cart is empty". When I click on Add to Cart it's not working either. It is working only when CP is logged in.

How can I solve this? any Configuration settings please.

I am using ExpressionEngine 2.6.1 and Store module is: 1.6.4

Ramesh Teegapur

Comment: You've tagged this CartThrob, I'm assuming you mean Expresso Store so amended.

Comment: Please post relevant sections of your templates so we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: There's really no settings in Store which could cause this. Is the product out of stock by any chance? Do you have any EE security options or plugins turned on which might prevent form submissions for logged out users?

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

[Store isn't adding products to the cart](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5236/store-isnt-adding-products-to-the-cart)

[Expresso Store: Update Cart button is not updating the cart](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10494/expresso-store-update-cart-button-is-not-updating-the-cart/10541#10541)

[Can't add items to a cart with EE 2.7 - Expresso Store](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13545/cant-add-items-to-a-cart-with-ee-2-7-expresso-store)

There's no conditionals in your template for logged in versus logged out in the relevant product tags are there?